# Able to read of an object in json format, but not able read its properties in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, object

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HKUv.png) 
I am able to access the object in json format, I can see all the properties and values, but I am not able to access individual property values.

I highly appreciate your help in advance !!!

```
 example.html 

<label>Name:</label>

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="age" placeholder="Enter age here">
<br>
<button (click)="send({ name : yourName, age : age})">send</button>

<h1 [hidden]="!yourName">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
{{myobj | json}}
{{myobj.name}}




example.ts

import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'hello-world',
 templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
yourName: string = '';
myname : string;
myage : number;
send : any (obj){
  console.log(obj);
  this.myobj = obj;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `myobj` defined?

Comment: Are you sure the syntax is correct?

I think it should be
`send : any = (obj) => {
          console.log(obj);
          this.myobj = obj;
    }`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, still not able to display property values. But I am able to console it.

Comment: @kkom can you try with my below code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below code works for me. I just defined `myobj:any` in the component and modified the `send` method signature .

hello_world.html

```
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="age" placeholder="Enter age here">
    <br>
    <button (click)="send({ name : yourName, age : age})">send</button>

    <h1 [hidden]="!yourName">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
    {{myobj | json}} 
    {{myobj.name}}
```

helloworld.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
 selector: 'hello-world',
 templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html'
})
export class HelloWorld {
yourName: string = '';
myname : string;
myage : number;
myobj:any;

constructor(){}

public send(obj:any):void{
  console.log(obj);
  this.myobj = obj;
}


}
```

Here is a link to a working plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/5eNU8ermOX90UThetAJX?p=preview

Comment: @kkom you are welcome .. can you please upvote if it's helpful.